# ASP.NET MVC - Unit Of Work vs Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, session, unit-of-work

Here at company we have several projects using ASP.Net MVC, jQuery, LinqToSql and StructureMap .

Suppose I have this situation: A Company edit page. This page has 2 tabs: Details and Employees. Details is just company details, such as name, phone etc. In Employees tab, I have a jquery grid will all Company Employees. These Employees are coming from a Session, because a user can edit an employee, delete, etc and all of these modifications will be set on the same Session. And, user can edit an employee so many times he wants, add a new employee, delete this same new employee and so on.

At the bottom of this page, I have Save and Cancel buttons. When Save is clicked, I get the employees from the Session and save to database. This kinda work.

One day, some collegue said that we should give up on using Session and start using Unit of Work. So, I began to read some articles, blogs etc about it.

What I didn't understand so far is how I can drop using Session and start using UoW to persist all my data... to persist correctly all of the things user did in the page.

I didn't find anything in some pratical ways so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.  Your employee data is coming from the session?  How does it get in the session to begin with?  That's a very poor choice, because two users can be using it simultaneously, and one can edit an employee but the other user will get old data, then if they edit the same user, one will overwrite the changes of the other.

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the Session. I have no intentions in get into details in how is coming from the Session, it's a poor choice, users can edit simultaneously etc. I'm trying to figure out how use unit of work to drop using all these Sessions. What's best technique etc.

Comment: @mystere. no, you are wrong. Session cannot be accessed by 2 users. a session is unique to each user. a users session can only be accessed by the 1 user, so storing data in the session will never be changed by another user

Comment: @Simon Halsey - Obviously.  You're not thinking it through.  The data is obviously being loaded from a database and put in the session, then it sits in the session for who knows how long until someone changes it.  That means the data in the session is quite possibly stale.  So when the system writes the changed data to disk, it might have already been changed, thus your changes would write over it.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. data in the db is changed by another user not the in the session, which is what i thought you were implying.

Comment: I wonder if there is a better this temporary management of data before sending it all to database.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, UoW is just a pattern for persisting data not a replacement for the Session.  The Session will still be used, it just that the UoW will be responsible with interacting with the NHibernate Session.  A typical UoW implementation may look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Employee model)
{
   using(IUnitOfWork uow = UnitOfWork.Start())
   {
       employeeRepository.Save(model);

       uow.Commit();
   }

   return Json("Success); 
}
```

Here you are explicitly marking the boundary of your transaction as opposed to passing a Session around. A great resource for implementing UoW for NHibernate can be found [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx).

Comment: Is there a wat to replace this temporary data manipulation? For now, I'm manipulating Session, but is there a way to replace that?

Comment: I'd have to learn more about your architecture.  Normally, the Session isn't used for temporary storage (especially in a web app).  When you say Session do you mean the NHibernate Session or some other store?

Comment: ASP.NET Session. In Employee's tab, all Employees are loaded from a ASP.NET Session, because an user can manage employees freely, such as, delete one, edit and in the end, user will hit save button to persist all Company data to database. And to save Employee data to database, I get from the Employee Session. I'm not using NHibernate. It's LinqtoSql

Comment: I can only guess what your colleague's suggestion is, but I can only presume that they were advocating moving away from storing state in the session and moving to a smaller use-case design whereas each and every change to Employee means an actual save to the database.

Comment: You may want to do a search for "LinqToSQL dead" and consider switching to NHibernate or EF...

Comment: @ShaneC - Linq to sql is not dead.  It's just aging.  VS 2010 even improved Linq to sql a small amount, but it's basically going to stay the same.  Nothing wrong with that, as Linq to sql is a good technology for many needs.  If you need somethin L2S doesn't provide, then you may need EF.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're getting at is you want a façade type pattern. You create an interface or base class to deal with getting & saving user data. you then create a concrete class that uses the session.

When you want to change to unit of Work, or any other mechanism, you just create a new concrete implementation & use that. you code is now oblivious to where your data is held.

Simon